# Validity of the realloc() function in C

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

Is

```
pointer = (int*)realloc(0, sizeof(int))
```

a valid expression?

I feel that since the first argument to `realloc` is a pointer and here it is 0(memory address reserved for the OS), this statement should not be a valid one. Can someone comment on the validity of the statement?

Comment: don't cast the return value of `malloc` (and friends) in C

Comment: Is 0 *really* reserved by the OS or is that just C's interpretation?

Comment: @Bathsheba: C simply guarantees that the null pointer will compare equal to 0.  Anything the OS does with address 0 is obviously specific to said OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid statement.

§7.22.3.5 from the C standard:

> ```
> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
> ```
>
> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the
> specified size. Otherwise, if ptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory
> management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the free or
> realloc function, the behavior is undefined. If memory for the new object cannot be
> allocated, the old object is not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Per C 2011 6.3.2.3 3, `0` may be used as a null pointer constant:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type **void ***, is called a *null pointer constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

In the call to `realloc`, the `0` argument is automatically converted to the type of the parameter, `void *`, per 6.5.2.2 7:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its declared type.

Answer (score 0):

From `man realloc`:

> If  ptr  is  NULL,  then  the call is equivalent to mal‐
>          loc(size), for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and ptr is
>          not  NULL,  then  the  call  is equivalent to free(ptr).  Unless ptr is
>          NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to  malloc(),  cal‐
>          loc()  or  realloc().  If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is
>          done.

In summary, its equivalent to `malloc()` when 1st parameter is `NULL`, so valid statement.